# Why is try block disabled for EOSIO smart contract

Tags: smart-contract

Why can't we use a try block inside a eosio smart contract? 
This is the error I get when I try to catch the exeption from eosio::require_auth2() function...

```
error:
      cannot use 'try' with exceptions
      disabled
    try
```

This is the code snippet under discussion:

```
 try
    {
        require_auth2(st.issuer, N(issue));
    }
    catch (...)
    {
        eosio::print("EXCEPTION CAUGHT");
    }
```

Comment: so why  use try? you can use has_auth.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Webassembly, the language contracts are compiled to does not support `try ... catch ...`. See https://github.com/WebAssembly/design/issues/1078